# PHP Mysql Insert só funciona no Chrome

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, firefox

Tenho uma pagina com um form onde é inserido nome, projeto, etc... só que quando clico no submit form no Firefox ou IE não funciona, Porém no Chrome funciona normalmente.

OBS:

1- Eu tinha um banco antigo. Quando eu mudo para este antigo endereço o Insert funciona em ambos browsers.

2- Tenho outra pagina que faz update dos dados e funciona normalmente para todos browsers, o problema só está na inserção de dados usando IE e Firefox.

3- Estou usando uma biblioteca para o db php mysql: https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

O problema seria no código, no banco ou no browser?

EDIT: Codigo:

```
function action_adddb () {
    global $db;

    $data = Array(
        'prname' => $_POST['prname'],
        'members' => $_POST['members']
    );

    $id = $db->insert ('users', $data);


    header ("Location: page_insert.php");
    exit;
}

$db = new Mysqlidb ('nomedohost', 'username', 'senha', 'nomedobanco');
if ($_GET) {
    $f = "action_".$_GET['action'];
    if (function_exists ($f)) {
        $f();
    }
}


<form name ="form1" class=" form-horizontal" action='page_insert.php?action=<?php echo $action?>' method=post>

<input type=hidden name='id' value='<?php echo $data['id']?>'>

<input class="form-control" type=text name='prname' required placeholder='Project Name' value="<?php echo $data['prname']?>">
<input class="form-control" type=text name='members' required placeholder='Members (First and Middle name)' value='<?php echo $data['members']?>'>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Create"  class="btn btn-primary text-center btn-block">

</form>
```

Comment: Para ajudar você melhor, poste o seu código na postagem.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli editei com parte do codigo

Comment: Dá algum erro de SQL?

Comment: @fernandoandrade nenhum erro

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o código:

```
function action_adddb () {
    global $db;

    $data = Array(
        'prname' => $_POST['prname'],
        'members' => $_POST['members']
    );

    $id = $db->insert ('users', $data);


    header ("Location: page_insert.php");
    exit;
}

$db = new Mysqlidb ('nomedohost', 'username', 'senha', 'nomedobanco');
if (isset($_GET['action']) && !empty($_GET['action'])) {
    $f = "action_".trim($_GET['action']);
    if (function_exists ($f)) {
        $f();
    }
}


<form name ="form1" class=" form-horizontal" action='page_insert.php?action=<?php echo $action?>' method="post">

<input class="form-control" type="text" name='prname' placeholder='Project Name' value="<?php echo $data['prname']?>" required>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name='members' placeholder='Members (First and Middle name)' value='<?php echo $data['members']?>' required>

<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary text-center btn-block">

<input type=hidden name='id' value='<?php echo $data['id']?>'>

</form>
```

Caso não dê, diga se ele atualiza a página após clicar no botão **Create** e se na url ele entra no arquivo `page_insert.php` com a query string `?action=nome_acao`

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi o problema, era um campo de date (que nao mencionei no codigo acima), eu só tirei ele e voltou a funcionar

Comment: Como encontrou a solução, pode, caso queira, fechar a pergunta, ou então postar uma resposta adequada. Digo isso pensando em futuros usuários que irão ler sua dúvida.